# how to change folder name in ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, directory, mv

when I try  to access to a folder using the terminal I got this message : "no such file or directory" this image will  this image explain every things

[image: terminal]

I try  to renamed by command "mv ",the same problem

think for helps

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
cd "Oxygen XML Editor 17"
```

When the directory name contains the spaces ...one need to use double quotes.

Comment: it works.thinks